# Ruby Select and Reject in one method

Tags: ruby, arrays, select, filter

Is there any built in method that would combine the functions of `Enumerable.select` (find all which the block equates to true) and `Enumerable.reject` (find all which the block equates to false)?

Something like

```
good, bad = list.magic_method { |obj| obj.good? }
```

Comment: My [methodfinder](https://github.com/citizen428/methodfinder) gem helps with questions like this one: `MethodFinder.find([*1..4], [[1,3],[2,4]], &:odd?) #=> [:partition]`.

Comment: OMFGBARBALE that would solve so many of my problems. D:

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Looks as if [`Enumerable.partition`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M001496) is exactly what you are after.

```
= Enumerable.partition

(from ruby core)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  enum.partition {| obj | block }  -> [ true_array, false_array ]
  enum.partition                   -> an_enumerator

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Returns two arrays, the first containing the elements of enum for
which the block evaluates to true, the second containing the rest.

If no block is given, an enumerator is returned instead.

   (1..6).partition {|i| (i&1).zero?}   #=> [[2, 4, 6], [1, 3, 5]]
```

Interesting, I didn't know that was there.   `ri` is an amazing tool...

Comment: Ruby is like that, though.  Eight times out of ten if you've thought of a useful method, it'll already be there.  :)

Comment: Yup, that's what I've found as well. :)

Comment: Was just directed to this method as well.  I'm new to Ruby on Rails and in looking through the documentation for Enumerable I thought, "If there's one module I should master, this is IT!"