# Ruby - Splititng Array after getting data from Mysql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following code to fetch the data from MySQL database into my rails controller

```
@main = $connection.execute("SELECT * FROM builds WHERE platform_type IS NOT NULL")
```

This returns a mysql2 type object which behaves like an array i guess.

I want to split this into 2 arrays, first one where platform_type is 'TOTAL' and everything else in the other array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It actually returns a [`Mysql2::Result`](http://rubydoc.info/gems/mysql2/0.2.6/frames/Mysql2/Result) object. Of course you can do

```
totals = []
others = []
main.each { |r|
  (r['platform_type'] == 'TOTAL' ? totals : others) << r
}
```

but why not use a rails way with smth like:

```
Builds.where("platform_type = ?", 'TOTAL')
Builds.where("platform_type NOT IN ?", [nil, 'TOTAL'])
```

Comment: undefined method `each_hash' for #<Mysql2::Result:0xb73e9790>

Comment: @sagarvikani Oooups, sorry, within `Mysql2` the method is called `each` rather than `each_hash`. My fault.

Answer (score -1):

Try array.select. Something like

```
total = @main.select { |build| build.platform_type == 'TOTAL' }
not_total = @main.reject { |build| build.platform_type == 'TOTAL' }
```

http://matthewcarriere.com/2008/06/23/using-select-reject-collect-inject-and-detect/

Even better, use Enumerable.partition as per this answer: [Ruby Select and Reject in one method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6778585/ruby-select-and-reject-in-one-method)

Comment: Uhmmm… `Mysql::Result` is not an `Array` descendant actually.